# Magento2: set product names in same page

Tags: magento2

Two languages (Store View) were added in addition to English.
To speed up the process rather than the addition of any translation I enter each language separately..
I want to add product names in this way (see attached image).
If there Magento-Extensions it can solved?
[image]

Comment: Its not possible to do it like this.

Comment: Magento manages language store view wise. This functionality can only be achieved via customization. I can guide you in case you need one.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be possible to add new attributes to the product (like "Product Name French", "Product Name Spanish", etc) ? Would that be the kind of thing you're looking for?